# Dropdown list in a cell of a JQGrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a jQGrid displaying the list of countries like so

```
function ShowCountry() {
    try {      
        $("#gridCountry").jqGrid({
            url: "/Master/GetAllCountry",
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: "Get",
            colNames: [ 'CountryID', 'Country Name', 'Abbreviation', 'Active', 'Last Modified Date','Select'],
            colModel: [
            { key: true, hidden: false, name: 'CountryID', index: 'CountryID' },
            { key: false, hidden: false, name: 'CountryName', index: 'CountryName'},
            { key: false, name: 'Abbreviation', index: 'Abbreviation' },
            {
                key: false, name: 'IsActive', index: 'IsActive', editable: true, edittype: 'checkbox', editoptions: { value: "True:False" },
                formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: { disabled: true }, align: 'center'
            },
            { key: false, name: 'LastModifiedDate', index: 'LastModifiedDate', formatter: 'date', formatoption: { newformat: 'd/m/Y' } },
            { name: 'Select', index: 'Select', sortable: false, formatter: DisplaySelectList }
            ],
            pager: "#divPager",
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
            height: "100%",
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: "Country List",
            emptyrecords: "no record to display",
            jsonReader: {
                root: 'rows',
                page: 'page',
                total: 'total',
                records: "records",
                repeatitems: false,
                id: '0'
            },
            autowidth: true,
            multiselect: false,
            loadonce: true
        }).navGrid('#divPager', { edit: true, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: true },
        {
            zIndex: 100,
            url: '/Master/UpdateCountry',
            closeonEscape: true,
            closeAfterEdit: true,
            recreateForm: true,
            afterComplete: function (response) {
                if (response.responseText) {
                    // alert(response.responseText);
                    document.getElementById('divAlert').style.display = 'block';
                    document.getElementById('divError').innerHTML = response.responseText;
                    //divError
                }
            }
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        document.getElementById('divAlert').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('divError').innerHTML = err;
    }
};

function DisplaySelectList(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    var edit = "<select name='gridDropdown'></select>";
    return edit;
}
```

I want to bind a dropdown on last column(Named Select) of this grid, I am using DisplaySelectList as a formatter method.

This Shows me the dropdown, but I want to fill the dropdown with some data using an Id. I Wrote onload for dropdown but in vain.

Please guide me on this

Comment: Probably you mix [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter) feature with editing. You use form editing in the grid and included `editable: true` for some columns. Which meaning in the case have the empty `<select>` in the last column? Why you need to display `<select>` **before** editing will be started. You wrote "I want to fill the dropdown with some data using an Id". And where is the source of the data? Are the data different for every row? Are the data in the response from `"/Master/GetAllCountry"`? Which format have the data from the response?

Comment: @Oleg : Thanks for your reply, Actually I am not looking for editing but for displaying the data, Sorry for the way I have put the question :( . But I need a dropdown with every row that is with every single object of country there would be the list of cities attached, and for every country the cities would be different. So, My city entity has a CountryId which gets me the cities, but I am wondering How to do it in JQGrid

Comment: **And where is the source of the data? Are the data different for every row? Are the data in the response from "/Master/GetAllCountry"? Which format have the data from the response?** I see no general problem with implementing you should just change the code of `DisplaySelectList` depend on where you get the information for content of every `select`. You should don't forget, that if you use simple select then **only one selected element** will be displayed for the user. Only if the user click on the select the user can see details. So one typically not use select for displaying of grid.